# Building two different lists in flutter custom scroll view

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-sliver

How can I build two lists to be displayed vertically so as one list of item is built and then the second follows in that vertical order.

Answer (score 12):

You can achieve this by using CustomScrollView with [SliverList](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/SliverList/SliverList.html).

Your solution would look something like this:

```
CustomScrollView(
  slivers: <Widget>[
    //list 1 (using builder)
    SliverList(
        delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
              (context, i) {
            return ListTile(...); // HERE goes your list item
          },
          childCount: 3,
        ),
    ),
    //list 2 (using list of widgets)
    SliverList(
        delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([
          ListTile(..),
          ListTile(..), //HERE goes your list item
        ]),
    ),
  ],
),
```

this will build one list after another as you scroll down. in the example above i have used both types of delegates available to build list.

1. [SliverChildBuilderDelegate](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/SliverChildBuilderDelegate-class.html) - needs a builder method which will be called to build widget for each list item. It is same as `ListView.builder()`
2. [SliverChildListDelegate](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/SliverChildListDelegate-class.html) - needs a list of widget which would be the items of the SliverList. It is same as `ListView(children: ...)`

Comment: Thanks alot  Harsh. It solved all my problems instantly. Kudos.

Comment: vote up and mark it correct, please. shamlessly_asking!! 

Comment: I couldn't. I have less than 15 reputation... I will one day.. The solution worked. Thanks alot . 

Comment: @HarshBhikadia can you help me with this question. I am also facing similar issues https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62437049/flutter-listview-builder-inside-sliverlist