# Flutter SliverList Error: TabbarView and Sliverlist not working

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to use Sliverlist in flutter app but it is giving me error. I tried multiple times but it is not working.

I am using TabbarView and Sliverlist. Earlier I was using Listview.builder and that was showing the data but scroll was not working. So, I plan to used Sliverlist instead of Listview.builder.

Here is the code.

```
slivers: <Widget>[
            SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                (context, index) {
        return 
      
        Container(
        //child: Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: Stack(
            children: 
            <Widget>[
        TabBarView(
          controller: _controller,
          children: [
           // Text("TAB ONE CONTENT"),
           Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.black87,
                ),
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, bottom: 5),
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                width: double.infinity,
              //  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child:
                SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                (context, index) {
                // ListView.builder(
                    //controller:  //_scrollcontroller,
                 //   itemCount: lists.length, 
                  //  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                     return buildList1(context, index);
                    }), 
                )   
                    

              ),
```

I am getting this error.

> A RenderPadding expected a child of type RenderBox but received a child of type RenderSliverList

Comment: you cannot have `SliverList` as a child of `Container`

Comment: @pskink thanks for the comment then should i use ListView.Builder to generate the list. Because if i use that then scoll didn't work.

Comment: why do you want to have one `SliverList` inside another `SliverList`?

Comment: @pskink its not like i want to use two SliverList. The thing is i need to generate multiple Lists items. Earlier i used ListView.Builder but my scrolling function didn't working. I am trying to implement this plugin. https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_easyrefresh

Comment: I think this widget can help you: SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: Container(
                height: 50,
                child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: 10,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Text('$index');
                    })),
          ),

Comment: @TrầnNhậtNamLê let me try this. I tried and i am still getting the same error. I used it insite TabBarView.

Comment: Give me more code. I haved tested with TabBarView and have no erorr.

Comment: @TrầnNhậtNamLê You can get the code from here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62437049/flutter-listview-builder-inside-sliverlist

Comment: I don't know what error here but first of all: you don't need to wrap the container inside SliverList. This is code i have test  body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: Container(
              height: 200,
              child: TabBarView(
                children: [
                   Text("This is call Tab View"),
                   Text("This is chat Tab View"),
                   Text("This is notification Tab View"),
                ],
                controller: _tabController,
              ),

Comment: @TrầnNhậtNamLê when i use Listbox builder my scrolling is stuck. Don't know why.